# VBA Problem with formula autofill in Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, autofill

In my excel workbook, I have two sheets (sheet1 & sheet2) with 3 tables each.
Each table has 3 columns, the first two have numbers and the last one has the formula =[@Column1]*[@Column2]
In the sheet1 they are named table1, table2, table3
In the sheet2 they are named table1_type, table2_type, table3_type.

I have created a macro to copy in one sheet all tables databodyrange to the other sheet's tables. To avoid the reference error after copying the data I replace the table name in the formula and it seems to work well.

My issue is that if I add a row to the table then there is no autofill with the formula  =[@Column1]*[@Column2]

Any idea how I could fix this?

[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmnMsJfbuxarj5Y4KXHquWS0C4m2nA?e=9Du4R0) is the onedrive link to my workbook

Thank you

```
Sub MoveTablesToSheet2()

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim tA As Range
Dim tB As Range
Dim t1 As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

For t1 = 1 To 3

'Table A = Source and B = Destination
Set tA = ws1.ListObjects("Table" & t1).DataBodyRange
Set tB = ws2.ListObjects("Table" & t1 & "_type").DataBodyRange

'-------------------------------------
'Delete table B but keep formulas
    If Not tB Is Nothing Then
    
        'tB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        'tB.Delete
        tB.Rows.Delete
        
    End If
'----------------------------------------------------
'count rows in table A, mandatory if table B is too small
If Not tA Is Nothing Then
i = tA.Rows.Count
  End If
'Add 1 row in table B for each row in table A
For y = 1 To i
ws2.ListObjects("Table" & t1 & "_type").ListRows.Add
Next y
'-------------------------------------------------------------

'copy table A data to table B
ws1.ListObjects("Table" & t1).DataBodyRange.Copy
ws2.ListObjects("Table" & t1 & "_type").DataBodyRange.PasteSpecial

'------------------------------------------------------
'Replace all references to Table A formulas in Table B

'Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False

ws2.Range("Table" & t1 & "_type").Replace What:="Table" & t1, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
'----------------------------------------------------------------

'Delete table A data but keep formulas
    If Not tA Is Nothing Then
    
        tA.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        'tA.Delete
        'tA.Rows.Delete
          
    End If
    
       Next t1

End Sub
```

Comment: Your macros stopped here: FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
I don't know what this is (I'm not an Expert), but without this it goes through.
I strongly believe after replacing you need to activate the (first) formula cell.(Put it in edit mode with keybord shortcut F2 or double click)
I tried it manually with double click + Enter. After that the autofill works.
I tried this ugly thing after the replacement:
**ws1.Range("D3").Formula = ws1.Range("D3").Formula**
to activate the cell. **IT WORKS!**
*Maybe also not good to delete all rows*. But I'm just a beginner in VBA.

Comment: Oh! maybe this is for Excel 365 FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2, dynamic arrays?

Comment: Yes I have Excel 365 so it might be this, I got this part with the macro recorder ;)
Thank you for F2, I didn't know this shortcut for the formula.
The problem with ws1.Range("D3").Formula = ws1.Range("D3").Formula  is that I never now the Range of my table as their size change. Si I have tried with this:
ws1.ListObjects("Table" & t1).DataBodyRange(3, 2).Formula = ws1.ListObjects("Table" & t1).DataBodyRange(3, 2).Formula
ws2.ListObjects("Table" & t1 & "_type").DataBodyRange(3, 2).Formula = ws2.ListObjects("Table" & t1 & "_type").DataBodyRange(3, 2).Formula

Comment: It seems it's working with ws2.Range("Table" & t1 & "_type[Column3]").Formula = ws2.Range("Table" & t1 & "_type[Column3]").Formula :)